# Slots not working in my VUE CustomElement (defineCustomElement)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have created this initialization of CustomElement in VUE 3 from various sources on the web (doc's, stackoverflow, etc).

Unfortunately, nowhere was discussed how to deal with slots in this type of initialization.

If I understand it correctly, it should work according to the documentation.
https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#slots

```
import { defineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

import audioplayer from "./my-audioplayer.ce.vue";
import audioplayerlight from "./my-audioplayerlight.ce.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const pinia = createPinia();
export const defineCustomElementWrapped = (component, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
    defineCustomElement({
        styles: component.styles,
        props: component.props,
        setup(props, { emit }) {
            const app = createApp();
            plugins.forEach((plugin) => {
                app.use(plugin);
            });
            const inst = getCurrentInstance();
            Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
            Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);
            return () =>
                h(component, {
                    ...props,
                });
        },
    });

customElements.define(
    "my-audioplayer",
    defineCustomElementWrapped(audioplayer, { plugins: [pinia] })
);
customElements.define(
    "my-audioplayerlight",
    defineCustomElementWrapped(audioplayerlight, { plugins: [pinia] })
);
```

I suspect that I forgot something during initialization and the contents of the slot are not passed on.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but we are working with this approach doing Web Components with Vue 3 and this workaround, adding Vue Component context to Custom Elements.

```
setup(props, { slots })
```

And then:

```
return () =>
   h(component, {
     ...props,
     ...slots
   });
```

Thanks @tony19, author of this workaround.